# Pull the data from mysql in PHP page and show in dropdown in html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a html page . Here is the code for this:

```
           <title>Post AD</title>
    </head>
  <body>

      <form method="POST" action="postad.php">

     <table>
    <tr>
    <td>AdName:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adname"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>AdCategory</td>
         <td>
            <select name="categories">
             <?php include 'getcategories.php'; 
             echo '<option value="'.$categoryname.'">'.$categoryname.'</option>';
             ?>
</select>";




  </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Contact Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contactnumber"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="image"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description"></td>
     </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Expiration Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="expirationdate"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="btn"><input type="submit" value='submit' name="submit"></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>


    </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

and I have another php page getcategories.php

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; 

            $sql = "SELECT CatName FROM categories order by CatName";
            $result = $db->query($sql);
           // $options="";
//echo "<select value='categories'>";       
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

        $categoryname=$row['CatName']; 
        //echo "$categoryname\n";
       //$options= '<option value="'.$categoryname.'">'.$categoryname.'</option>'; 
       // echo "$options\n";
    // echo '<option value="'.$categoryname.'">'.$categoryname.'</option>';

}
// echo "</select>";
?>
```

The main objective of getcategories.php page is to pull the data from database and the page postad.html page is to show the data of getctegories.php to the dropdown list in postad.html.Is there  a way to not use java script and only use php and mysql to do this?Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: *"and the page `postad.html` page is to show the data of getctegories.php to the dropdown list in `postad.html`"*  - You want to run PHP inside `.html`?

Comment: yes........I want to show the mysqli data in html page.....the mysqli query in html page shows error hence I created new php page for database operation

Comment: Either you rename your `.html` files to `.php`, instruct Apache to treat `.html` as PHP, or use Ajax.

Comment: It seems like you already have it figured out.  Uncomment the `<option>` in the php page and remove the `<option>` from the HTML page assuming you already did what Fred is saying.  I missed that you named that file .html.  PHP code is not evaluated in a .html file by default, so Fred's suggestion is what you need.

Comment: I changed the file name to .php......thank you...:)